# How do you make python script run faster?

Tags: python, linux, performance, pythonanywhere

I noticed a big difference when I was running a script on [pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com). The times were like 7-8 times shorter than running the same script on my PC and i want to understand why. I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running on Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM Processor(6M Cache, up to 3.40 GHz), 8GB ram and SSD hard driver with speeds over 500MB/s.
Could someone explain to me what I have to do to achieve the same performance? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: How were you timing it?

Comment: What is it that you are doing?

Comment: I crawl a website doing a lot of things. Most of them are sending POST data to the server.

Comment: The network might be the bottleneck on home PC.

Comment: So you're doing some network requests, obvious first guess would be that your connection to the server is slower then the connection that pythonanywhere has. But this is not specific enough, what is your definition of crawling, and what do you mean by "doing a lot of things"? Sending POST data might be slow as most broadband connections have lower upload then download speeds, something the pythonanywhere server will probably not experience.

Comment: @Yossi I have 100MB connection and the ping in the website is like under 10msec most of the time. From pythonanywhere i have over 100msec

Comment: you have 100MB upstream? That's impressive :-) *Normally* you have 100MB down and something completeley different (lower) up

Comment: @Blubber I was thinking if python has a configuration file or something where you can boost the performance. Like apache or mysql

Comment: @FredrikPihl only 10MB upstream, but i dont upload files . I think 16Kbps upstream it will be enough for running my script.

Comment: you don't send files but you do POST. This might be the bottleneck since the latency is proably greater from @home then from .com. Hard to tell though unless you post some code, either here or link to github/gist/pastebin etc (if large)

Comment: Unless you are sending a bunch of small POST requests latency is probably not going to have anything to do with it. However, if you are doing large POSTs then that 10mbit upload might be the bottleneck. Again, you are not specific enough for us to say anything useful. And no, there is no config file that you can alter to get any speed-up.

Comment: also, pythonanywhare runns on Amazon EC2, who knows whats going on there wrt parallelism, load-sharing etc...

Comment: I tried to speed up using threads . Here is a snapshot of my code http://pastebin.com/NSenWPXm

Comment: Not all of the code is there unless I don't know how to use it (I can only see the first 22 lines), but you realize that the two calls to sleep() will slow things down. And I wonder if the "please click" means that some human action is needed.

Comment: I use those sleeps on pythonanywhere because the server cant send the response fast enough. Thats what is pissing me off so bad. Using sleeps and still 7-8 times faster.

Comment: Say what? I'm guessing the call to openurl() is blocking, so it should block until a response is received. Are you sure the code on pythonanywhere is actually doing to correct thing? Or are they blocking outgoing HTTP requests for some reason (I have absolutely no experience with pythonanywhere whatsoever).

Answer (score 7):

In 9 out of 10 cases, I'm wrong when I reason why something is slow. If you look at my reputation, then this means: I stopped trying this many years ago because it simply doesn't work.

Add logging to your script that tells you which step takes how much time. Run the script on both sides and compare the results. That's the best way to find out why something is slow or fast.

Comment: I did, the result is amazing. The login part took like 0.00something on pythonanywhere and on my PC between 5-7sec. I also checked the upstream from my PC to the web server , no fluctuation - over 900K constantly

Comment: Check if pythonanywhere is actually receiving the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Use threads in your program. I have a python program that downloads about 2KB of data for each of 500 stocks from finance.yahoo.com to my home laptop and writes each to a separate file. I have a typical internet connection for home (802.11G). With a single thread it takes 2-3 minutes, but with 40 threads it takes less than 4 seconds. I have Windows XP on a Intel Core 2 CPU T5600, 1.83 GHz and 2 GB RAM that I got in 2005.

Comment: As i answered before, i use them > http://pastebin.com/NSenWPXm But still is slower :(

Comment: Before you start using threads you should try to benchmark what part of the code is running slowly. Try to time a couple requests (say 100) both locally and on pythonanywhere, you can calculate mean and variance easily, and see what's going on. If the network is really the bottleneck then threading might help, but if the bottleneck is something else then threading probably won't do you any good.

Comment: As I said above I can only see 22 lines of the code, and you use sleep(). As far as I can tell, threading will not make it run 7-8 times slower if coded properly. Does crawling send each page to your machine? If so then that combined with sending POST data sounds to me like I/O rather than CPU so threading should help.

Comment: Yeah, I also support multithreading if you have thousands of independent computations.